# Template for Messaging Interface Control Document

Tags: templates

Is there a template that allows me to define a table for messaging interface control document that will look something like this:

[image: Message Interface Control Document]

I am looking for something that will allow me to specify the message by defining the elements within the message as something like this:

```
\makemessage{FooMsg,3,16,"Foo Message Definition"}
\addelement{FooMsg,0,0,3,"Spare"}
\addelement{FooMsg,0,3,13,"Message Unique ID"}
\addelement{FooMsg,1,0,8,"Error ID"}
\addelement{FooMsg,1,8,8,"Module ID"}
\addelement{FooMsg,2,0,16,"Reserved"}
```

Comment: Is there any news here? It is quite unlikely that something like that already exists.

Comment: I found nothing. Nor did I have the time to learn how to create my own.

Comment: Added an answer that I think fulfils the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be interested in the [`bytefield` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield?lang=en). You can represent what you want as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

    \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.1em, endianness=big]{16}
         \bitheader{0-15} \\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 0}
         \bitbox{13}{Message Unique ID} & \bitbox{3}{Spare}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 1}
         \bitbox{8}{Module ID} & \bitbox{8}{Error ID}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 2}
         \bitbox{16}{Reserved}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
    \end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: bytefield example with normal fonts]

If you add `boxformatting={\centering\small\ttfamily}` to the parameters of the `bytefield` environment, you get something even more similar to what you require:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.1em, endianness=big, boxformatting={\centering\small\ttfamily}]{16}
         \bitheader{0-15} \\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 0}
         \bitbox{13}{Message Unique ID} & \bitbox{3}{Spare}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 1}
         \bitbox{8}{Module ID} & \bitbox{8}{Error ID}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Word 2}
         \bitbox{16}{Reserved}
         \end{rightwordgroup}\\
    \end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image: bytefield example with \ttfamily and centering]

Comment: You can use this solution to create later some commands to do as you wanted.